# Facebook FQL: compare ISO-8601 time stamps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Facebook recently changed the way they represent timestamps from unix time to ISO-8601. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/).  Before it was possible to write an fql statement like:

```
SELECT eid FROM event WHERE start_time < 1345178483
```

where 1345178483 is unix time. Are queries like this still possible with ISO-8601?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to replace your time stamp with an ISO-8601 formatted string:

```
SELECT eid FROM event WHERE start_time < "2012-08-17T00:41:23-04:00"
```

Note that the old `now()` method in FQL doesn't work. [Bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/271667989601814)